# How to get result of Insert

Tags: php, sql, mysql

This is a fairly basic question, I currently have two tables and in the second table there is a foreign key column for table `A`.

### Table A:

```
id       Name
----------------
1        Name1
2        Name2
```

### Table B:

```
id       Name      Parent
-------------------------
1        John      1
```

What happens:

- My PHP script inserts `Name1` into Table `A` and mysql inserts the id.
- My PHP script needs to insert `John` into Table `B` AND set `Parent` to be the `id` of the query that was just inserted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the first insert, you can do:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
$row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
$lastInsertId = $row[0];
```

Alternatively, you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). However, from the manual:

> mysql_insert_id() will convert the
>   return type of the native MySQL C API
>   function mysql_insert_id() to a type
>   of long (named int in PHP). If your
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column has a column
>   type of BIGINT (64 bits) the
>   conversion **may result in an incorrect
>   value.** Instead, use the internal MySQL
>   SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() in an
>   SQL query.

Because of this, the first method I listed is preferred if your column uses -- or may use in the future -- `BIGINT`.

Comment: Note that `mysql_insert_id()` does the exact same thing.

Comment: @Vincent Savard: Not if the datatype is `BIGINT`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the last inserted id.

> mysql_insert_id — Get the ID generated
>   in the last query

**Caution:**

> mysql_insert_id() will convert the
>   return type of the native MySQL C API
>   function mysql_insert_id() to a type
>   of long (named int in PHP). If your
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column has a column
>   type of BIGINT (64 bits) the
>   conversion may result in an incorrect
>   value. Instead, use the internal MySQL
>   SQL function LAST_INSERT_ID() in an
>   SQL query. For more information about
>   PHP's maximum integer values, please
>   see the integer documentation.

**Example:**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ..........");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Answer (score 2):

After executing the `INSERT` query with `mysql_query`, you can use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the ID that was used for the previously inserted row.